# Auto-populate site tree items for SilverStripe site

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

I am still learning SilverStripe, and right now, I have a list of 50-60 pages I have to create for a site. It was suggested that I find a way to auto-populate the SilverStripe site tree with some code in order to save time (as opposed to manually creating each page one at a time). I have never tried something like this before (with or without a CMS). I know what the parent and child page names are, and I suppose I would need to create a loop to build out the child pages for each parent.

Is this something that is possible in SilverStripe? Would a for loop be the best approach or is there a more efficient way? If I can make creating these pages easier, it would be great for me for this project and future ones, so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

My understanding of this question is that you want to pre-populate the pages and their content programmatically rather than manually entering them in the CMS. There are a few projects that might help you.

1. Populate module (https://github.com/dnadesign/silverstripe-populate)
2. SilverSmith (https://github.com/unclecheese/SilverSmith)

Or you could simply override DataObject::requireDefaultRecords and build the pages out there. I would often use that method for functional or one-off type pages (e.g. ShoppingCart).

Comment: silversmith is afaik 3.0 only, but populate module works great! just define a yml file and run the populate task. It's a great time saver

Answer (score 3):

There is also a [Site Tree Importer from SilverStrip Labs](http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/silverstripe/sitetreeimporter). It's hosted on [Github](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-sitetreeimporter)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
<ul>
<% loop $Menu(your id here) %>
    <li>
        <a href="$Link" class="$LinkingMode">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
        <% if $Children %>
        <ul>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <li>
                <a href="$Link" class="$LinkingMode">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
                <% if $Children %>
                <ul>
                <% loop $Children %>
                    <li>
                        <a href="$Link" class="$LinkingMode">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
                    </li>
                <% end_loop %>
                </ul>
                <% end_if %>
            </li>
        <% end_loop %>
        </ul>
        <% end_if %>
    </li>
<% end_loop %>
</ul>
```

Keep in mind that the code may differ a little and that this is for SilverStripe v3+

Comment: I like this idea (and it should work as I am using SilverStripe 3.1)! But how or where would this loop need to be placed in order for it to run? I'm guessing I would need it to run when doing a Dev/Build? And is the loop meant to run based on a text file with a list of of the site's nav links?

Comment: Include this in your SideBar.ss file and than include that file in your main Page.ss file.

Comment: I think this may not work for what I want to do...this should work in creating a navigation template, but I'm not sure if this will create the pages in the site tree in the SilverStripe CMS backend...What I want to do first is to auto-populate the site tree with the pages if that is possible.